# error: expected identifier before 'public'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, game-boy-advance

I'm currently trying to make a GBA game for the GBA Game Jam, anyways I've gotten rid of basically every error when trying to compile I think these last errors are connected to each other though so anyways here's the error that I think there all connected to:

```
error: expected identifier before 'public'
   38 | class gbaEngine :: public engine
```

Here are the rest of the errors:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before 'public'
error: cannot call member function 'virtual bool gbaEngine::OnUserCreate()' without object
  190 |     gbaEngine::OnUserCreate();
cannot call member function 'void gbaEngine::Start()' without object
  189 |     gbaEngine::Start();
error: cannot call member function 'virtual bool gbaEngine::OnUserCreate()' without object
  190 |     gbaEngine::OnUserCreate();
```

Anyways here are the parts of the script you would probably need to see (although if you think it might be somewhere else feel free to ask about it):

**engine.cpp:**

```
#include "GBA3D/engine.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <strstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include "toolbox.h"

struct vec3d
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct triangle
{
    vec3d p[3];
};

struct mesh
{
    std::vector<triangle> tris;
};

struct mat4x4
{
    float m[4][4] = { 0 };
};

class gbaEngine :: public engine
{
public:
    //Stuff in here
};
```

**engine.h:**

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <strstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include "toolbox.h"

//#define REG_TM2D -0x4000                        //0x4000 ticks till overflow
//#define REG_TM2CNT TM_FREQ_1024                 //we're using the 1024 cycle timer
//#define REG_TM3CNT TM_ENABLE | TM_CASCADE

//typedef uint32_t u32;
//typedef int32_t  s32;

bool m_bAtomActive;


class gbaEngine
{
public:
    //Stuff in here
};

#endif
```

If you can help please do

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the following:

```
class B : class A
```

This will make class B inherit class A.

You have:

```
class gbaEngine :: public engine
```

instead of:

```
class gbaEngine : public engine
```

Comment: Then I get this error:


error: redefinition of 'class gbaEngine'
   38 | class gbaEngine : public engine

Comment: Wait. Why are you defining your class again in Engine.cpp? Engine.cpp should have just the implementations for the methods defined in Engine.h

Comment: Replace the definition of **class gbaEngine** in Engine.h with the one from Engine.cpp